# How to delete and retain a particular value in a cell based on the value of a certain cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

How to make a vb code to delete the contents of Column B when i entered a specific value in column A?
Example: If cell A1=apple, cell B1 should delete whatever value it have. But if cell A1=grape, cell B1 should retain whatever value it have.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variations of this question are all over the internet.

This example is taken from the link below with minimal changes

[Example](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/57975-delete-rows-if-criteria-need-visual-basic-applications-help.html)

```
Sub test()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow
If range("A" & i) = "apple" Then
    With range("B" & i)
        .ClearContents
        .FormatConditions.Delete
    End With
End If
Next i
End Sub
```